# Select cells and automatically apply the formula to the right of each

Tags: vba, excel

Thank you guys. Based on responses, and going little deeper I kept my code like this:

```
Public Function LowHigh(custo As Integer)
    If custo > 10.99 And custo <> 0 Then
        LowHigh = "1.4"
    Else
    If custo < 11 And custo <> 0 Then
        LowHigh = "1.35"
    Else
    If custo <= 0 Then
        LowHigh = "Valor Inválido"
    End If
    End If
    End If

End Function
Public Sub lorh()
ActiveCell.Formula = "=LowHigh(" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).End(xlToLeft).Address & ")"

End Sub
```

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGDc2.png)

On selecting the right value in question and press the button, the forfunção LowHigh runs, the problem is that it needs to be done cell by cell, and I need to select the entire range to the left and click the button cells immediately right interval are filled with the formula as shown below:
[Final image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGDc2.png)

I tried something like this:

```
Public Function LowHigh (cost As Integer)
     If cost> And cost 10.99 <> 0 Then
         LowHigh = "1.4"
     else
     If cost <11 And cost <> 0 Then
         LowHigh = "1:35"
     else
     If cost <= 0 Then
         LowHigh = "Invalid"
     end If
     end If
     end If
    
end Function
Public Sub lorh ()
Range ("ActiveCell", "ActiveCell"). FormulaR1C1 = "LowHigh = (" & Range (ActiveCell.Offset (0, 0). End (xlToLeft)). & Address ")"
   
end Sub
```

but it did not work, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

No offense, but you really need to read any tutorial at all on using if...else because everything is wrong with how you use them. You are inserting if statements inside other if statements instead of saying `else if`, let me show you.

```
if something then
    blah
else
    if something else
        blah else
    end if
end if
```

This is above is what you are doing, this is what you meant

```
if something then
    blah
else if something else then
    blah else
else if something else again then
    blah else again
end if
```

The difference should speak for itself with proper indentation (which your code does not have).

Edit: Oh and I forgot the most obvious:

```
If cost> And cost 10.99 <> 0 Then
```

This makes absolutely no sense. You are saying `if cost is greater than and (which is an operator) and cost 10.99 <> 0 (which means nothing) then. If statements in VBA are practically really what you would say in plain english:

```
If cost > 10.99 and cost <> 0 then
```

I guess this is what you meant, but that would be a bit unnecessary to have that `and cost <> 0` part.

Comment: Okay my friend, thanks for the advice, I really feel the need for a good tutorial because I'm a beginner, I'm in this thing vba only a few days and I think my code is heavily influenced by pascal programming. Me And this brings some advantage, but also many difficulties. Anyway thank you.